# How to fail the jenkins job based on the condition?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In my scenario i am using **Jenkins freestyle job** to clone the git repository, after that it should parse the keywords like (Error, ERROR, error) in **log files** of particular path in my Workspace, if the condition finds the error the Jenkins should fail the job **else** it should proceed further steps.

I tried this command to parse log files

egrep -rqw 'ERROR|Error|error'  $WORKSPACE

Comment: You can use 'exit 1' in your conditional statement to fail the build.

Comment: Added as answer since this worked. Kindly accept the answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your scenario, in your conditional statements you can include 'exit 1' to fail your build.

exit(0) is equivalent to exit(EXIT_SUCCESS).

exit(1) is equivalent to exit(EXIT_FAILURE).